# Is this valid syntax?

Tags: bug

> You've earned the "Enlightened" badge (First to answer and accepted with 
>    score of 10 or more) for "Did Aaron Levenstein say
>   'Statistics are like bikinis'?".

"First to answer and accepted"???

Answer (score 2):

I read it as two clauses, with the second clause describing the properties of the answer

"first to answer"

and

"accepted, with a score of 10 or more"

Answer (score 0):

It's alright just put in some imaginary commas or brackets to correct the syntax. And imagine that "answer" and "accepted" are states.

```
First to answer, and accepted with score of 10 or more

First to answer. And First to accepted. But also with score of 10 or more
```

Comment: Both your suggestions are grammatically incorrect.